# Hadoop Spark Invalid URI for NameNode - file://has no authority for AWS s3 bucket

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, apache-spark

Currently setting up Spark/Hadoop teststack for the first time and have run into an issue I'm hoping the community can help with.

The goal is to run a simple jar file via spark submit that will read from and write to an S3 bucket.

Spark is installed, and now I'm working on Hadoop for the hdfs/s3 features.

I followed a guide for setting up on windows and all seemed well until I run the start command which results in:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URI for NameNode address <check fs.defaultFS>: file:/// has no authority.
```

The details in core-site.xml were originally pointing to localhost:9000, I need it (I believe) to point to the s3 bucket that I'm trying to work with.

From other guides and answers I now have this as my core-site.xml:

```
<configuration>

<property>
    <name>fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId</name>
    <value>xxx</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey</name>
    <value>xxx</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
    <value>s3n://myBucketName</value>
</property>
```

I'm also new to AWS/s3 and think that the issue could be with the bucketname location but unsure what the endpoint should be, or even if this is the root of the cause.

Thank you in advance for any help.

EDIT:  I tried running hdfs on the bucket from command line and received the error that site-core.xml could not be found, currently all on my xml files are located in hadoop/etc/hadoop

I copied the site-core from there to hadoop/conf and it no longer errors, it does tell me there is no filesystem for s3 but, is this correct?  Should those files reside in conf or etc/hadoop?

Comment: seems like a permissions issue on your bucket

Comment: @Havnar, thanks for taking the time to look at the question, there shouln't be any issues with permissions and I jsut discovered another issue that might have something to do with it, would you mind taking a look at the edit pease?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, `/etc/hadoop/conf ` is the default location for hadoop config

Comment: @Havnar, that does make sense however I followed this guide which suggests leaving them in hadoop/etc/hadoop : http://toodey.com/2015/08/10/hadoop-installation-on-windows-without-cygwin-in-10-mints/

Comment: Wow... you are doing this on Windows? Strange choice of OS for this... you can find more info on setting S3 as your HDFS location here:  https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/index.html

Comment: @Havnar, not my decision I'm afraid.  thank you for the link, having a look now